# Dynamic Form Builder in Asp.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, formbuilder

In our current application there is a new requirement of our client.As they told that they need n numbers of forms at different stages of their business and those are changing time to time. Even a new forms can be added. 
Their requirement is once the product is delivered to them they will not come back to us again and again for each change and will create those form by their own.

**Simply they want a user interface where they can create the form by drag and drop manner.**

What they want :

1. In our application there will be a form building section where a non technical person can be able to create a form.
2. Mapping the controls with existing data of their existing database so that the form is populated with the corresponding data ( data will be inserted into the database using another user interface).
3. Once the data is populated they will take the print out of the filled up form and will proceed as per their business flow.

As they introduce new form time to time we can't provide any predefined template to them and they are not agree to design the form in HTML.

Is there any way of doing this in Asp.Net MVC (without using any CMS ).

Comment: Introduce them to a CMS of your choice, tell them that their original idea is absurd, and then run away screaming.  This is the type of project that you could spend years working on (and pulling your hair out), and they'd never be satisfied with the result.

Comment: take a lock [https://formbuilder.online](https://formbuilder.online/)

Comment: check out http://form.io  and github I'm working on some integration similar to your app